# Salesforce Flow - Send Email Action - started throwing GACK error while testing

Tags: salesforce-flow

I created a Salesforce Flow that sends a weekly update to 30+ community users.

I put logic in the flow to create list of all emails then filter/sort to only 5 emails, then use the "Send Email" action to send the email.

While testing the flow logic, the Send Email action worked fine.    But after 6 debug tests it is now giving me the following error:

Error Occurred: An error occurred. Try again, or contact Salesforce Customer Support and provide this error ID: 1743424483-83192 (1025524993)

I thought maybe it was because I was sending the same email message to the same recipients several times so I changed the test emails.   But still getting the same error message.

Any ideas???

P.S.  The flow dynamically creates the email body that includes a table with list of content that is new or updated.   Not sure I can use Email Alert for this.